# Resolving ambiguous implicit conversions in Scala

Tags: scala

Any way to opt to use asJavaIterable in the following? I know I can just spell out that particular function name, but I'm wondering if I can just declaritively specify the type I want. I'm also curious why asJavaIterable isn't taking precedence over asJavaCollection.

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> Iterable(0,1):java.lang.Iterable[Int]
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Iterable[Int]
 required: java.lang.Iterable[Int]
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method asJavaIterable in object JavaConversions of type [A](i: Iterable[A])java.lang.Iterable[A]
 and method asJavaCollection in object JavaConversions of type [A](i: Iterable[A])java.util.Collection[A]
 are possible conversion functions from Iterable[Int] to java.lang.Iterable[Int]
       Iterable(0,1):java.lang.Iterable[Int]
               ^
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible to limit the scope of the import so that `asJavaCollection` will not be considered:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.{asJavaCollection=>_,_}
```

This says, "import all members of JavaConversions, except asJavaCollection".

However, I think its preferable to import `JavaConverters` and make your conversions explicit.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

Iterable(0,1).asJava
```