# Can I introduce an implicit precedence relation between packages as with objects?

Tags: scala, implicit

I was wondering how to place effectively the same implicit conversion in more than one package in such a way that importing the contents of one is enough, but importing all doesn't introduce conflicts. Regardless of what's your opinion about the idea as stated (I can guess), it's *almost* possible:

```scala
    trait syntax
    object syntax {
        implicit class syntaxIntExtension(a :Int) {
            def times2 = a * 2
            def times3 = a * 3
        }
    }

    trait extension extends syntax
    object extension {
        implicit class dialectIntExtension(a :Int) extends syntax.syntaxIntExtension(a) {
            override def times2 = a + a
            def times4 = a.times2.times2
        }
    }

    object lazyUser {
        import syntax._
        import extension._
        1.times2
        1.times3
        1.times4
    }
```

The caveat here is that the scopes `syntax` and `extension` must be `objects`; `package objects` won't work, and I have absolutely no idea what I could even try in Scala 3. Can I somehow use `syntax` and `expansion` identifiers as normal scopes, containing normal 'non inner' classes? The only ways I can think of is

- to have `syntaximpl` and `extensionimpl`, and fill `syntax` and `extension` up to the brim with type aliases and `val`s. Me not like.
- declare everything I want as inner types of some wrapper `trait`s and compose `syntax` and `extension` by mixing in a long list of such wrappers. Ugh.

Now, I can make it work relying solely on the other implicit precedence rule of being 'more specific than', but it comes with some drawbacks, such as the need for Scala 2 style pseudo extension methods even in Scala 3. I wonder thus if there is something I haven't thought about when trying to exploit the former rule.